# inactivating button after changing content from drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, jsonselect

Save button is only active when an instruction text is select from a drop down list. 
The problem is, if I made changes to a selected instruction text, the button is still active. 
I’ve tried replacing on-select with ng-change but didn’t solve the problem.
How can I inactivate the button once any changes done to the input instruction text?

**Controller**

```
$scope.validInstructionText = true;

$scope.checkInstructionText = function(instruction, $index) {
  $http.get("/api/instructions?searchInstructionText=" + instruction).then(function(response) {
    if (instruction === response.data[0].instructionText) {
      return $scope.validInstructionText = false;
    } else {
      return $scope.validInstructionText = true;
    }
  });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-init="initUpsert()">
  <div class="input-field col m4">
    <label class="active" for="instructionText">Instruction Text</label>
    <autocomplete
      ng-if="!currentQuestion.id || currentQuestion.status === 'flagged'"
      ng-model="currentQuestion.Instruction.instructionText"
      data="instructionChoices"
      attr-placeholder="Instruction Text"
      attr-input-class="validate"
      attr=id="instructionText"
      on-type="getRemoteInstructions"
      on-select="checkInstructionText"
      autocomplete-required="true"></autocomplete>
    <input ng-if="currentQuestion.id && currentQuestion.status !== 'flagged'" type="text" ng-model="currentQuestion.Instruction.instructionText" ng-disabled="true">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col m12 right-align">
      <button class="modal-action waves-effect btn waves-green teal white-text btn-flat" ng-click="spellcheck(true)" ng-show="currentQuestion.status === 'review' && isModified === true" ng-disabled="validInstructionText">
      Save and Add Another
      </button>
      <button class="modal-action waves-effect btn waves-green teal white-text btn-flat" ng-click="spellcheck(flase)" ng-show="currentQuestion.status === 'review' && isModified === true" ng-disabled="validInstructionText">
       Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-include src="'/views/modals/spellCheckModal.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide just the json data that the get will return so I can reproduce

Comment: Put in this {{validInstructionText}} as the text of your button. Maybe validInstructionText does not change as you expect

Comment: could you fork this codepen ( http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/qNmALP ) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Your autocomplete directive- does it have protected or closed scope?

Comment: i believe in autocomplete, on-type behaves similar to ng-change.  i placed checkInstructionText function into the getRemoteInstruction function in the controller and it worked. thanks for the help and advice.